# How can I delete only one part of the cookie set by my domain (several others set for other apps)?

Tags: javascript, cookies

`document.cookie` gives me something like:

> "cookie_name_1=623222.88839338.818181.383; SnapABugHistory=4#; optimizelyEndUserID=aaa1111111; my_cookie_name=%5data%7Bfrom%3Arails"

I only want to remove the `my_cookie_name=%5data%7Bfrom%3Arails` and leave the rest intact.

What's the best way to do this from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it with a past `expires` date -- simplest is probably the unix epoch (just `new Date(0)`):

```
document.cookie = 'my_cookie_name=; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
```

This will only affect the cookie of the name given at the start of the string. To affect the other 3 cookies, you would have to repeat for each:

```
document.cookie = 'cookie_name_1=; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'SnapABugHistory=; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
//...
```

That's because the getter and setter of `document.cookie` do differ. While you ***get*** a concatenated list of all available cookies, you can only ***set*** one at a time.

See the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.cookie) for more details.

Comment: Nice..this is really helpful.  I didn't realize the get/set difference existed here.

Comment: I realized this means I was using was already working, I was just erroneously thinking it was clearing all the cookies!

Answer (score 0):

[http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie](http://jquery.cookie)

Allows you to set/get cookies by name, use it to set my_cookie_name to 0 or ""

Comment: Thanks for the good tip, but I was looking to do it purely from javascript (I am using jQuery already, though, so this is good to know for the future)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Quirks Mode post about cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). It will give you a great explanation about how to use cookies.

Near the end (section **The scripts**) there are three functions that you might find useful, namely `createCookie(name,value,days)`, `readCookie(name)` and `eraseCookie(name)`, wich is exactly what you want.

Of course, this is pure javascript. If you're using a js framework (such as jQuery), you're better of using the framework's built-in functions